# Gap between left drawable and text in textview

Tags: android, layout

There is a long gap between drawable left and the text in text view.

[image]

I have added drawable padding but that does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:background="#0B6159"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Add Address"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

How can I bring the drawable close to my text

Comment: Do you want the 'Add Address' near to the '+' button?

Comment: Yes and everything at the centre

Comment: As Rishav Singla answer suggests, remove the gravity=center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove `android:gravity="center"`from textview :**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="#0B6159"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Add Address"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Use **drawablePadding** for maintain gap according to your need.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. But in that case wouldn't the position of the text and drawable vary depending on screensize? How do I make sure that everything is in the centre?

Comment: I tested by removing the gravity and adding drawablepadding. In this case it seems that the padding is only on the right. Not on the left

Comment: Change your textview width from match parent to wrap content and then useandroid:layout_gravity to set everything in centre

Comment: This works, but the background color gets restricted to the wrapping. But this seems  like a minor issue. Will find a workaround to this

Comment: if you want to give background color, give it to your parent layout i.e Linear layout in your case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rishab, found a work around

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0B6159">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Add Address"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Dude no need to add another extra linear layout for that use copy and paste below code : just give background color to your parent layout android:background="#0B6159" and set android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" to your textview with width wrap content

Comment: your comment is correct. But I have other items within the parentlayout. So would not like those to change color as well. Hence added the extra layer